# How to await a write function inside a get function with Firebase Cloud Function for Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, I don't really know how to write JS, I am developing a mobile app in Flutter, and I would be grateful for some help and clarifications regarding Future/Promises in JS.

I got a collection of posts for each user, and I want to create an .onCreate function which when a user posts a new post (a new document is created inside the 'posts/userId/user_posts' collection), then it gets all the user's followers (from a collection 'user_followers/userUid') and for each follower, it writes the postUid and postOwnerUid to that follower's newsFeed collection ('user_news_feed/followerId').

This is what I got right now, but I am walking blind, since I really don't know JS and I don't know how can I await a write function while inside a get function.

And how do I prevent Cloud Timeouts? If for instance the user has 1000 followers, how can I prevent Firebase from shutting down my function and making sure all the followers are notified?

```
exports.writeToUserNewsFeed = functions.firestore
.document('posts/{userId}/user_posts/{postId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const postData = snap.data();
    const postUid = postData['post_uid'];
    const userUid = postData['user_uid'];
    const postCreationDate = postData['post_creation_date'];

    var docRef = db.collection('user_followers').doc(userUid).collection('followers');

    docRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            db.collection('user_news_feed')
            .doc(doc.data['uid'])
            .collection('feed')
            .document(postUid)
            .set({
                'post_uid': postUid,
                'user_uid': userUid,
                'post_uid': postCreationDate,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), in a background Cloud Function like an `onCreate()` for Firestore, you need to return a Promise when all the asynchronous work is completed. So in your case, one possibility is to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) because you don't know upfront how many documents are in the `followers` subcollection. Since `Promise.all()` returns a single Promise you can include it in the Promise chain that you need to return in the Cloud Function.

```
exports.writeToUserNewsFeed = functions.firestore
    .document('posts/{userId}/user_posts/{postId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const postData = snap.data();
        const postUid = postData['post_uid'];
        const userUid = postData['user_uid'];
        const postCreationDate = postData['post_creation_date'];

        var followersColRef = db.collection('user_followers').doc(userUid).collection('followers');

        return followersColRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {   // <= See return here

            const promises = [];

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                promises.push(
                    db.collection('user_news_feed')
                        .doc(doc.data['uid'])
                        .collection('feed')
                        .doc(postUid)
                        .set({
                            'post_uid': postUid,
                            'user_uid': userUid,
                            'post_uid': postCreationDate,
                        })
                );
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);   // <= See return here

        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
        })

    });
```

---

Note that instead of using `Promise.all()` you could also use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) but there is a limit of 500 operations for a batched write.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it that way, and I get in my Firebase console the log that the function was executed "ok". However, no new document was written in my user_news_feed?

Comment: There was a mistake in the initial code: `...collection('feed').document(postUid)` shall be `.collection('feed').doc(postUid)`. Note that I've also renamed `docRef`to `followersColRef`, it makes more sense. One important thing to note: if the doc corresponding to `collection('user_news_feed').doc(doc.data['uid'])` does not exist, it will **not** be created => Only the doc in the `feed` subcollection will be created.

Comment: Thank You, you are right, now it works perfectly, I also had some small syntax issues since I am used to Dart, but the code works, and the Cloud Function works correctly. 
You are a life saver!